# Laravel 5.5 Multiple user type nested route group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have two user types: Operations and Maintenance.
All routes that the Operations user type can be accessed by Maintenance user type but not all routes that Maintenance have can't be accessed by Operations.

Here's my existing code.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'maintenance'], function(){
    //routes here

    Route::group(['middleware'=>'operations'], function(){
         //routes here

    });
});
```

kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'revalidate' => \App\Http\Middleware\RevalidateBackHistory::class,
    'dev' => \App\Http\Middleware\isDev::class,
    'operations' => \App\Http\Middleware\operations::class,
    'maintenance' => \App\Http\Middleware\maintenance::class,
];
```

middleware/operations.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $a = UserAccess::where(['employee_id'=>\Auth::user()->id, 'user_type_id'=>1])->first();
    if($a){
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

But it doesn't work. Maintenance can access all it's routes but doesn't have access to operations and Operations doesn't have access to any route at all.

NOTE: Both groups are inside the auth middleware group

Comment: Show us your `app/Http/Kernel.php` code as well as your `operations` middleware code

Comment: @NikolaGavric code has been edited.

Answer (score 1):

Found a work around for this. I created another middleware that caters both Operations and Maintenance by passing two parameters to that middleware specifically 1 = Operations and 2 = Maintenance and had the middleware check for access. Here's the code:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'access:2,2'], function(){
    //Routes that can be accessed by Maintenance user type
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>['access:1,2']], function(){
    //Routes that can be accesed by Operations and Maintenance user type.
});
```

Here's the middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ops, $main)
{
    $a = UserAccess::where('employee_id',\Auth::user()->id)->whereIn('user_type_id', [$ops, $main])->first();
    if($a){
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**EDIT:**

Optimized code to remove parameter redundancy.

Web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'access:2'], function(){
    //Routes that can be accessed by Maintenance user type
});

Route::group(['middleware'=>['access:1,2']], function(){
    //Routes that can be accesed by Operations and Maintenance user type.
});
```

access.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $ops, $main = 0)
{
    $a = UserAccess::where('employee_id',\Auth::user()->id)->whereIn('user_type_id', [$ops, $main])->first();
    if($a){
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed an additional array inside of your `where` query, try changing the code inside of your `operations` middleware like so:

```
$a = UserAccess::where([
         ['employee_id', \Auth::user()->id],
         ['user_type_id', 1]
     ])->first();
```

**EDIT:**

Then try moving both of your `middlewares` into `$middlewareGroups` below `web` middleware, like this:

```
'web' => [
    ...
],
'operations' => \App\Http\Middleware\operations::class,
'maintenance' => \App\Http\Middleware\maintenance::class,
```

**EDIT 2:**

Change the code for `$a` variable to this

```
$a = UserAccess::where([
         ['employee_id', Auth::user()->id], //Hence there is no \ before Auth
         ['user_type_id', 1]
     ])->first();
```

Then at the top of that same file include the following `use`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

**EDIT 3:**

You can add additional parameters to the `request` which are then sent forward, like this:

**Middlewares/operations.php**

```
function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    ...
    $request->attributes->add(['passedOperations' => true]);
    return next($next);
}
```

**Middlewares/maintenance.php**

```
function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    ...
    if($request->get('passedOperations')) {
        return next($next);
    } else {
        //didn't pass operations
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with my query cause if I put the operations group in separate with maintenance, it works smoothly. It only stops working when I put the group inside another group.

Comment: Hmm, then you can try to actually use those middlewares as `group` middlewares instead of as standalone middlewares, check the edit

Comment: Same output? Does it throw any errors, can you explain the behaviour, what happens exactly?

Comment: Cant access routes on operations middleware group. But I can access all routes on maintenance middleware

Comment: What does can't access really means? The server gives you 401, 403 or you get an error, or you get a blank page or it redirects you somewhere?

Comment: It redirects me to '/' which means that the condition on my middlware/operations.php failed.

Comment: Try dumping your `$a` inside of your `operations` middleware, and tell us what do you get

Comment: Dump returns null

Comment: Okay, now change the code for `$a` with the code I posted in my answer and tell me what does the dump give?

Comment: Still gives null

Comment: Check my edit number 2, keep an eye on the comment inside the code

Comment: Same output, still returns null.

Comment: Then you need to check that the data you are looking for does exist in your database, can you confirm this? Just dump both `Auth::user()->id` and then check your database for that `UserAccess`

Comment: It would fail since I am logged in with maintenance user type, what I expected was since operations group is inside the maintenance group, maintenance user type would be able to access operations group.

Comment: In the middleware you define who has access, so if you for example say that both `maintenance` and `operations` users have access, then you will pass the request and actually hit your `endpoints` inside of `operations` middleware.

Comment: i tried adding the middleware as array like `Route::group(['middleware'=>['operations', 'maintenance']], function(){` but my problem is the operations middleware returns true but the maintenance returns false so it stil ldoesn't go in. Is there any way to tell laravel that if one middleware returns true, accept the access.

Comment: Found a work around for my problem, will post as answer.